# Pass data from Form1 to class1 using delegate and event

Tags: c#, winforms, events, delegates

I know how to pass data using event and delegate from Form2 to Form1 (backwards actually).
But I would like to know how to do it appropriately from Form1 (main form) to Form2.
Imagine Form2 and some center form to show some progress (with a progressbar) which would be common for plenty of other forms.

This is how I would like to look like:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public delegate void ProgressEvent(object obj);
    public event ProgressEvent OnProgressShowing;

    public Form2()
    {

    }

    private void ShowingProgress(object obj)
    { 
         //calling this method from Form1
         //But it must be PRIVATE!
    }
}
```

How to do it?

Like?

```
     Form2 f2 = new Form2();
     f2.OnProgressShowing += new Forms.ProgressEvent(?? ?what to put inside here?? I cannot access a private method on form2 ???);
```

I know one option is to create delegate and event on Form1, and pass a Form1`s reference to Form2, and subscribe to an event from Form2. But this is not what I would like. I would then have plenty of delegates and events in each of the other forms which would call this form2.

Comment: Which form is displaying the progress to the UI?  Which form is the one that knows that progress needs to be updated?  You've put an event on `Form2`, but you also indicate that it's `Form2` that needs to be updated, not Form1.

Comment: Form2 is dispalying progress. Data are on other forms (Form1, Form3, Form4 - these are only example form names). And progress would be shown on Form2. This question is making my hair gray for ages :)

Comment: So, event is on the form that needs the update goes from? In my case, even should be on form1, which will update form2. Am I right? ... What I was trying to do, If I have plenty of forms with data to show progress, on each of them I have to create an event, right? Or I can create a single one, and use it on each of the forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your first form is creating an instance of your second form and "owning" that instance, it is *appropriate* design for the method on `Form2` that updates the UI based on the current progress to be `public`, and for the other forms calling it to call that method.  There is also no need for `Form2` to have an `event` at all, since it is not the one informing other forms that something has happened.

In this case, when creating a design document to indicate the relationships between these forms, we can say that `Form1`, or other forms *have* a `Form2`.  A HAS-A relationship makes sense here.  For `Form2` it's goal is simply to display progress based on information provided by another class, so having a public method for another class to tell it to display progress is *correct*.

You're missing up a reversed relationship.  If the child form needed to inform the parent forms of something, then `Form2` would have an event, and in the handler of that event the forms creating it (i.e. `Form1`) would generally be calling *their own private methods* in the handler, or possibly accessing other public methods of `Form2` to pull or push data out of it.

The idea here is that is'a appropriate for `Form1` to "know about" `Form2`.  It's appropriate for it to have a reference to it, and to know about whatever it exposes publicly.  `Form2`, however, shouldn't know *anything* about what form creates it.  It should be able to display progress for *any* form that can tell it what progress to show.  If it needs to accept a reference to `Form1` or know anything about it at all, then that can't happen.  By using an event on `Form2` *when it needs to pass information **out*** to the form that creates it, it can avoid needing to know what form that is.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. Big, thx for learning me that a "child" form does not need to use an event to inform the parent form. Really didn`t know that. I really appreciate it. This is a giant leap in my knowledge. Thank you ones again Servy (the Man :) ).

Comment: @MitjaBonca Your statement is incorrect.  You *should* use an event for a child form to provide information to it's "parent" form.  **Your child form is not providing information to its parent; your parent is providing information to its child**, and in that case, there is no need for events.

Comment: Yes, my parent form is the one that is providing info, child form is there only to show this info to the user - nothing else!